# How to select specific PLL?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

The Altera FPGA Max10 has 4 PLL's available (1-4).

Qustion: Is there a way how to determine which PLL I can use for my design or how Quartus selects the PLL's?

And which clock input for the specific PLL I should use for the ADC1 when I have two options on the same bank?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Altera .qsf file you can specify the placement for an instantiated PLL, using:

```
set_location_assignment PLL_{number} -to "{path}"
```

E.g.:

```
set_location_assignment PLL_1 -to "my_module:my_module_e|pll"
```

But special placement is not a requirement, and can be left to the placement tool, unless there are some special requirements, like speed or size constrains and limitations.

Comment: thanks for the answer - finally I know how to specify the PLL. Which clock input I should use for PLLx when I have to clock sources on the same bank?

Comment: See the Users Manual for selection of clock input, since there may be special constrains.  However, why do you have two clock inputs; unless for a reason, remove one of those.

Comment: if I specify in the .qsf file the PLL do I also need to assign the PLL with the asignment editor first?

Comment: The assignment editor is a visual editor for the .qsf file, so you can use the assignment editor to update the .qsf file, if you don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Ok got it..! Last simple question: If you have a FPGA-CLK, is it mandatory to set this clock signal as global-clock or is it done automatically? If I need to declare a global clock, is it also done with the assignment editor? Thanks in advance

Comment: There are different kind of clocks depending on the device, e.g. global clock, regional clock, local clock, so see the device users manual for details.  Typically it is not required to specify the clock type, since the place and route tool (PnR) will handle this, but if PnR cant resolve it, then it may be required to specify the clock types for different networks.  I you have many clocks, then it is wise to do a clock budget to be sure that the required clocks are available in the design, but if you design is simple, then let the tool handle it, unless the PnR tool generate a can't fit error.